# How do I get a real Id when i can't provide marriage records

Tags: usa, paperwork, applications

I was married in 1997 in New Jersey for maybe a week when I found out my husband and his kind family were only using me to obtain a green card. Therefore, I went back to California and left him. I tried to have all my documents in my maiden name from dmv but was informed that my married name is now my legal name. 20 years later, I need my marriage certificate and New Jersey send me an official sealed letter informing me they can not locate my records.  Now what do I do? I gave them all the information I could remember.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Travel, not even a bit.

Comment: @NeanDerThal this question is about Byzantine bureaucratic requirements for a particular type of driver's license the main benefit of which for most people is that it may be used at airport security checkpoints in the United States.  So it is certainly about travel, maybe even more than a little bit.

Comment: What exactly did the official letter say? What was the extent of “all the information I could remember”? Did you try the municipality where the marriage license was originally obtained?

Comment: This should be on https://law.stackexchange.com/ or reddit.com/r/legaladvice.

Comment: Was the marriage legally ended (by divorce or annulment)? If not, real id is only one of many problems and you need a lawyer.

Comment: Did you get a legal divorce or annulment? If not, you should speak to a lawyer about getting that done. If you are currently a California resident you can probably get divorced right there in California, but you need a lawyer to make sure everything is right.

Comment: IME, New Jersey marriage records are often kept at the municipal rather than state level. Do you remember where in NJ you were married? If you were married in Newark, call the city of Newark. If you were married in Atlantic City, they should have your records, etc.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I agree with your advice, but in addition to needing a lawyer to make sure the divorce or annulment is done right, she probably also needs a marriage certificate.  So deciding to get that taken care of probably wouldn't obviate the need for an answer to this question.

Comment: Julia: Which agency sent you that letter saying they can't locate your records?  What exactly did the letter say?  Can you scan it or take a picture, black out the identifying information, and [edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/168281/edit) your question to add the image?  What city or town issued the marriage license and certificate?